# create red and green dots on image

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, imagemap

I am adding my code here. I have a table named points, with fields id,name,and status.
values have status 0 and 1

1. If value have a status 1,then show it as a green dot
2. If value have a status 0,then show it as a red dot

I tried it in a image map
I want to show name of value on mouseover too
Here is my code:

```
    <html>



    <map name="map1" id="_map1">
        <?php  
foreach ($points as $point)
{
    $name=$point->name;
    $status=$point->status;
 if($status==1){ ?>
        <area shape="rect" coords="10,15,18,20"  href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/green.jpg"   alt="" title="" onmouseover="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
        <?php } else if($status==0) {?>
        <area shape="rect"  coords="0,0,50,50" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/red.jpg"   alt="" title="" onmouseover="<?php echo $name; ?>"/> 
<?php } }?>
                        </map>
         <img id="map1" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/rectangle.png" usemap="#map1" border="0" width="800" height="600" alt="" />


</html>
```

actually am getting co-ordinates on image.but only onclick it can view. its not displaying with color. i want see that green and red dots on image
 I want to generate co-ordinates dynamically too.
 Anybody aware about this,then please help me.

Comment: Width and height should both be in `px`  not in `%`

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a sample style you could use to it adjust the position.
Also `border-radius` should be 50% for a circle not 100%

```css
.circle_green {
      
      padding: 10px 11px;
      background: green;
      height: 2px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 2px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="circle_green">
      </div>
```